# What is the basis of the space of d-variate polynomials of order not exceeding q?

Tags: polynomials

I was wondering if someone could tell me what  the basis of the space of d-variate polynomials of order not exceeding q is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the set of $d$-variate monomials of order not exceeding $q.$

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. If we have two variables $x,y$ and $q=2$, you mean that $\{ 1,x,y,x^2 ,y^2 ,xy\}$ is basis?